# How to specify range for minor version in Debian package control file "Depends:" "Pre-Depends" clause

Tags: debian, packaging, apt

This is regarding debian control file for ubuntu package.

I need to specify dependency list in "Depends:" / "Pre-Depends"  clause  with packages as illustrated below

My package is "foo" . it depends on package "bar" .
Allowed  versions of "bar" are 2.X.Y where  X=3 and  and Y>=5  (lets call 2 as major, X as Minor version, and  Y as sub minor version)

So basically I want to specify that I am okay with minor version 3 and  sub minor versions ranging from 5  to 9

To give examples

*#  my specs should allow below versions*
bar-2.3.5,
bar-2.3.6,
... ,
bar-2.3.9

*# my specs should disallow below versions*
bar 2.2.X,
bar 2.3.4,
bar 2.4.X,
bar 3.X.Y,

**so the question is -  In my control file is below the right way to specify?**

```
# Control file 
Package: foo 
Depends: bar (>=2.3.5), bar(<<2.4.0)
```

Is there a more compact/ appropriate way?

Especially if I make a simplifying requirement change - and say  I am ok with minor version .5 and any sub minor versions (  2.5.X - )  then **is there a way to match any among ( 2.5.0, ..., to 2.5.9)  with a single == like expression ?**

I looked at https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html but that does not provide me enough direction

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I verified that this way of specification does work

```
Package: foo
Version: X.X.X
... 
Depends: bar (>=2.3.5),  bar (<<2.4.0)
```

However the undesirable side effect of this is that the dependency "bar" appears twice if I examine dependencies of "foo" using "apt cache depends"

*And just for fun. If you understand hindi you may say the dependency  appears bar bar :-)*

```
  #apt-cache depends foo
  PreDepends: bar
  PreDepends: bar
```

So while I have a working soultion,
I am still looking for a more elegant way More answers welcome (so my answer isn't accepted)